# Create a periodic background task in iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background-service, background-task

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms application for vehicles tracking by gps... the app must check my server for data every X minutes, if new data found just show a local notification containing some of those data.

For that I created a background service with a broadcast receiver in the Android app, so this service is triggered automatically every 5 minutes to check the server.

Of course the user can start or stop this service easily at anytime.

```
startService(androidService);

stopService(androidService);
```

So my question; is there a solution to do the same work in the background in iOS devices ? I'm beginner in iOS apps development can someone help me with a sample of code? thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no periodic background task for iOS. It would be more efficient if your server sent a push notification when there was new data rather than have the app poll for new data.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11, is it possible to do it from a SQL Server ?

Comment: Not from an SQL server directly, but you shouldn't be querying an sql server directly from a mobile app anyway.  You will need a server capable of performing the periodic query against the database and then sending the push notification.

Comment: thanks again @Paulw11, I will research this topic. If you have some resources about that it would be great to share them with me.

Comment: @Arselan From iOS 13 , there is a `BackgroundTasks` Service .Use the `BackgroundTasks` framework to keep your app content up to date and run tasks requiring minutes to complete while your app is in the background. Maybe it's be helpful for you .

Comment: hey @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks, I need to run those tasks even when the application is completely closed (not in the background )... is it possible with this framework ?

Comment: @Arselan Oh, it is not possible . As far as I known, it not supports in iOS now .